# How to get claims from Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have followed the following tutorial 
[Azure AD B2C: Call an ASP.NET Web API from an ASP.NET Web App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi)

I am able to run the app.

When the authorisation code is received I put a break point on line `var code = notification.Code;`and I am able to see all the claims received.

But when I try to print the claims nothing is displayed and the app exits. It shows a null object reference on the following line

`string a = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Country).Value;`

Any idea how I can print all the claims. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```cs
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
{
    // Extract the code from the response notification
    var code = notification.Code;

    string signedInUserID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    string a = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Country).Value;
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
    try
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, Scopes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: Handle
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Double check the claim type :) If you get a null ref there, then the claim isn't there with that type.

Comment: I have put a break point on notification.code. Im able to debug and see all fifteen claims when I try assigning it to a string , it fails with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot of the debugger view? Feel free to black out values if you don't want to show them

Comment: Do the identity claims contain a `country` or `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/country` claim? `ClaimTypes.Country' is mapped to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/country`.